# Multiple Record Update based off Select Results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcommand

Here is my base SQL query in SQL Server 2008:

```
SELECT userID
FROM coreUsers 
INNER JOIN pluginSales ON coreUser.userID = pluginSales.userID
WHERE (coreUser.CurrentYear = '2014') 
  AND (pluginSales.PaidShipping = 'Yes') 
   OR (coreUser.IsContract = 'Yes')
```

**Just tested on 12/19/2014 again, this returns 61 results.**

I need to be able to update the `pluginSales` table column `ShipppingDate` for all the records that result from the above statement.

`coreUser.userID` is my unique key that auto increments.

`pluginSales` has a column `ShippingDate` that is just a standard `varchar` that I need update to `'12/16/2014'` if the record was set to 2014 (`coreUser.CurrentYear`) and they PaidShipping (`pluginSales.PaidShipping`) OR if they are a contracted customer (`coreUser.IsContract`)

EDIT #1

I tried the following...

```
UPDATE       pluginSales
SET                ShippingDate = ''
FROM            coreUsers AS cu INNER JOIN
                         pluginSales AS pis ON cu.userID = pis.userID CROSS JOIN
                         pluginSales
WHERE (cu.CurrentYear = '2014') AND (pis.PaidShipping = 'Yes' OR pis.IsContract = 'Yes')
```

**Just tested again on 12/19/2014 this modified 554 records (my whole pluginSales database)**

This affected ALLLLLL of my rows and not just the specific ones. Please advise.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type) - you should always use the most appropriate data type. **WHY** are you storing a **DATE** (`ShippingDate`) as a `varchar` - use a `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)` instead! That's what these types are there for!

Comment: The reason why this is like that is because i don't have a client side validation for a specific "date".  I know its a bad idea, but for the current system I have running its what I need it to do and is working as intended.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run the select

```
SELECT *
FROM pluginSales PS
INNER JOIN coreUsers CU ON CU.userID = PS.userID
WHERE (CU.CurrentYear = '2014')
    AND (PS.PaidShipping = 'Yes')
    OR (CU.IsContract = 'Yes')
```

then change only first line to UPDATE ...

```
UPDATE pluginSales SET ShippingDate = '12/16/2014'
FROM pluginSales PS
INNER JOIN coreUsers CU ON CU.userID = PS.userID
WHERE (CU.CurrentYear = '2014')
    AND (PS.PaidShipping = 'Yes')
    OR (CU.IsContract = 'Yes')
```

Your Where clause has an OR. You may want to explicitly group using parenthesis ().

Comment: This doesn't work it actually freaking effected 552 rows when the original SELECT statement only returns 61 items.  This obviously doesn't work

Comment: @eqiz, I added a select which is syntactically identical to the one you have but slightly modified to ensure the comparability to update. If your where clause is correct, both those select and update should effect identical number of rows.

Comment: Your fix worked perfectly thanks for that change/update!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with an `update` and `join`:

```
UPDATE cu
    SET ShippingDate '12/16/2014'
FROM coreUsers cu INNER JOIN
     pluginSales pis
     ON cu.userID = pis.userID
WHERE (cu.CurrentYear = '2014' AND (pis.PaidShipping = 'Yes') OR (pis.IsContract = 'Yes');
```

You may actually want this `where` clause:

```
WHERE (cu.CurrentYear = '2014') AND (pis.PaidShipping = 'Yes' OR pis.IsContract = 'Yes');
```

Note that you shouldn't be storing dates in strings.  Instead, you should be using the native `date` or `datetime` types.  If you have to store dates as strings, you should use YYYY-MM-DD format, so operations such as `order by` and comparisons will work on the values.

Comment: This is the EXACT same as amit_g.. it doesn't work it freaking effected my whole database and NOT just the records it was suppose to.  The original select statement I gave above only affects 61 returns while yours just affected my whole database

Comment: @eqiz . . . I would check the alternative `where` clause.

Comment: @eqiz . . . Then the version with your original `where` clause would appear to have the correct logic.

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 didn't like your statement so it reformated it to what I have above in my Edit #1.  It has to be the statement itself thats causing the issue. I didn't change anything all i did was copy 'n paste